# How to save an image from Picturebox that load from camera?

Tags: vb.net, aforge

I create a simple program that getting image from camera and display it in picturebox using a Aforge library. However, when I try to save the image from picture box. It prompt an error like this " 'System.Runtime.InteropServices.ExternalException' in System.Drawing.dll. A generic error occurred in GDI+. "

I did some research but not found any helpful solution.

Below are my following code use to save the image:

```
Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click

        PictureBox1.Image.Save("C:\a.jpeg", ImageFormat.Jpeg)

End Sub
```

**Updated Code :**

```
Imports AForge
Imports AForge.Video
Imports AForge.Video.DirectShow
Imports AForge.Imaging.Filters
Imports AForge.Imaging
Imports System.Drawing.Imaging

Public Class Form1

    Dim Filter As FilterInfoCollection
    Dim Camera As VideoCaptureDevice


    Dim MINR As Integer = 0
    Dim MING As Integer = 0
    Dim MINB As Integer = 0
    Dim MAXR As Integer = 255
    Dim MAXG As Integer = 255
    Dim MAXB As Integer = 255

    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

        Filter = New FilterInfoCollection(FilterCategory.VideoInputDevice)
        If Filter.Count > 0 Then
            For Each ITEM In Filter
                ComboBox1.Items.Add(ITEM.Name.ToString())
            Next

            CheckForIllegalCrossThreadCalls = False

            Me.Location = New System.Drawing.Point(Me.Location.X, 0)
        Else
            MsgBox("NO Camera Found")
        End If
    End Sub

    Private Sub ComboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles ComboBox1.SelectedIndexChanged

        Camera = New VideoCaptureDevice(Filter(ComboBox1.SelectedIndex).MonikerString)
        AddHandler Camera.NewFrame, New NewFrameEventHandler(AddressOf Video_NewFrame)
        Camera.Start()
        ComboBox1.Visible = False
    End Sub

    Private Sub Video_NewFrame(sender As Object, eventArgs As AForge.Video.NewFrameEventArgs)

        Dim ORIGINAL As Bitmap = DirectCast(eventArgs.Frame.Clone(), Bitmap)
        Dim FILTER As Bitmap = DirectCast(eventArgs.Frame.Clone(), Bitmap)


        Dim CFILTER As New ColorFiltering
        CFILTER.Red = New IntRange(MINR, MAXR)
        CFILTER.Green = New IntRange(MING, MAXG)
        CFILTER.Blue = New IntRange(MINB, MAXB)
        CFILTER.ApplyInPlace(FILTER)


        Dim GRAY As Grayscale = Grayscale.CommonAlgorithms.BT709
        Dim IMAGING As Bitmap = GRAY.Apply(FILTER)


        Dim BLOBS As New BlobCounter()
        BLOBS.MinHeight = 10
        BLOBS.MinWidth = 10
        BLOBS.ObjectsOrder = ObjectsOrder.Size
        BLOBS.ProcessImage(IMAGING)

        Dim Rectangle As Rectangle() = BLOBS.GetObjectsRectangles()
        If Rectangle.Count > 0 Then
            Dim Rectangle2 As Rectangle = Rectangle(0)
            Dim STYLE As Graphics = Graphics.FromImage(ORIGINAL)
            Dim CLR As New Pen(Color.Lime, 5)
            STYLE.DrawRectangle(CLR, Rectangle2)
            STYLE.Dispose()
        End If

        PictureBoxDefault.Image = ORIGINAL '
        PictureBoxFilter.Image = FILTER
    End Sub


    Private Sub TrackBarMINR_Scroll(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles TrackBarMINR.Scroll
        MINR = TrackBarMINR.Value
        LabelMINR.Text = "MINR: " & MINR
    End Sub

    Private Sub TrackBarMING_Scroll(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles TrackBarMING.Scroll
        MING = TrackBarMING.Value
        LabelMING.Text = "MING: " & MING
    End Sub

    Private Sub TrackBarMINB_Scroll(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles TrackBarMINB.Scroll
        MINB = TrackBarMINB.Value
        LabelMINB.Text = "MINB: " & MINB
    End Sub

    Private Sub TrackBarMAXR_Scroll(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles TrackBarMAXR.Scroll
        MAXR = TrackBarMAXR.Value
        LabelMAXR.Text = "MAXR: " & MAXR
    End Sub

    Private Sub TrackBarMAXG_Scroll(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles TrackBarMAXG.Scroll
        MAXG = TrackBarMAXG.Value
        LabelMAXG.Text = "MAXG: " & MAXG
    End Sub

    Private Sub TrackBarMAXB_Scroll(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles TrackBarMAXB.Scroll
        MAXB = TrackBarMAXB.Value
        LabelMAXB.Text = "MAXB: " & MAXB
    End Sub

    Private Sub Form1_FormClosing(sender As Object, e As System.Windows.Forms.FormClosingEventArgs) Handles Me.FormClosing
        Try
            Camera.SignalToStop()
        Catch ex As Exception
        End Try
    End Sub

    Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnSave.Click

        PictureBox1.Image.Save("D:\a.png", ImageFormat.Png)

    End Sub


End Class
```

Comment: Don't save in `C:` and set `PNG` instead of `Jpeg` as destination format. See also that you don't have invalidated the source frame somehow.

Comment: @Jimi I already try change the path and file format. It still prompt above error that I mentioned.

Comment: Can you show the updated code and how the frame you're trying to save got into that PictureBox? Are you drawing the Bitmap or assigning the object to the property? Have you maybe called Dispose() on the source frame (or `GC.Collect()` when and source object went out of scope)?

Comment: @Jimi I just updated whole code. Please check.

Comment: Remove this thing: `CheckForIllegalCrossThreadCalls = False` (don't use it anymore). Fix the threading issue properly: the `NewFrame` event is raised in a background thread. You cannot access UI elements directly from that thread. Plus, you have to dispose of the previous `PictureBox.Image` before assigning a new one (e.g., call `PictureBoxDefault.Image?.Dispose()` before `PictureBoxDefault.Image = SomeBitmap`).

Comment: You didn't specify whether you're using the AForge PictureBox control of the AForge framework (`AForge.Controls.PictureBox`) or the standard `System.Windows.Forms.PictureBox`.

Comment: @Jimi im using  standard System.Windows.Forms.PictureBox. I try modify my code based on your advice.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue.
The code below is now working for me.

```
Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
    Dim img As Bitmap = PictureBox1.Image.Clone
    img.Save("Z:\test.bmp", System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Bmp)
End Sub
```

Just change "Z:\test.bmp" to your directory, haven't tried any other image formats but this is the only way I have gotten it to work so far.